# Некорректная работа псевдокласса :not

Tags: html, css, style

Есть структура html типа

```css
menu .item {
  color: green
}

menu>.block>[class~='rec']:not([class~='mark'])>.item {
  color: black
}
```

```html
<menu>


  <div class='block'>

    <div class='rec'>
      <a class='item' href='df'>dddd</a> //black
    </div>

    <div class='rec'>

      <a class='item' href='/remont/'>ssss</a> //black - должно быть green


      <div class='block'>

        <div class='rec mark'>
          <a class='item' href='df'>dddd</a> //green
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


  </div>


</menu>
```

Что не так?  По моей логике 2 и 3 элементы должны быть зелеными, но зеленый только 3, будто не исполняется условие :not([class~='mark'])

ставлю вместо

```
 :not([class~='mark'])
```

вот это, например

```
:not([class~='block'])
```

Все корректно отображается  (color=black)

Comment: зачем вам такие сложности с селекторами?

Comment: меньше кода и ресурсов на php  только вот из-за этйо строчки

Comment: Явно же, что заголовок вопроса должен звучать, как: "Почему в моём примере кода присутствует так много ничего незначащих пустых строк-отбивок?"

Comment: перенес код в сниппет. Судя по всему все работает так, как и ожидалось. Попробуй изменить пример так, чтобы ошибка воспроизвелась

Comment: после редактирования, непонятно почему во втором случае должно быть `green`

Comment: В принципе не понимаю зачем так усложнять, идея в том чтоб делать все элементы зеленые если есть дочерние элементы? Почему не сделать как первый вариант который я предложил в ответе?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понимаю почему просто через класс не выбирать.

```css
.rec .item{
  color: black;
}

.rec.mark .item{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <div class='block'>
    <div class='rec'>
      <a class='item' href='df'>dddd</a> //black
    </div>
    <div class='rec mark'>
      <a class='item' href='/remont/'>ssss</a> //black - должно быть green
      <div class='block'>
        <div class='rec mark'>
          <a class='item' href='df'>dddd</a> //green
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</menu>
```

Если интересно почему у Вас не работает я расписал в комментарии, а также  почитайте [Комбинаторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

```css
menu .item {
  color: green
}

menu>.block>[class~='rec']:not([class~='mark'])>.item {
  color: black
}
```

```html
<menu> //menu>.block>[class~='rec']:not([class~='mark'])>.item
  <div class='block'> // выбрали только этот элемент так как стоит комбинатор > после menu
    <div class='rec'> // выбрали этот элемент так как в нем нет класа mark
      <a class='item' href='df'>dddd</a> // применили цвет так как указан комбинатор >
    </div>
    <div class='rec'> // выбрали этот элемент так как в нем нет класа mark
      <a class='item' href='/remont/'>ssss</a> // применили цвет так как указан комбинатор >
      <div class='block'> // стили не применяются так как блок не прямой потомок menu
        <div class='rec mark'>
          <a class='item' href='df'>dddd</a> // стили по умолчанию
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня наоборот, вы ошиблись с синтаксисом, скорее всего

```css
el .item {
  color:green;
}

el > .block > [class~='rec']:not([class~='mark']) > .item {
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<el>


        <div class='block'>

           <div class='rec'>
             <a class='item' href='df'>dddd</a>
           </div> 

           <div class='rec'>
]
             <a class='item' href='/remont/'>ssss</a>
           
            
             <div class='block'>

                 <div class='rec mark'>
                    <a class='item' href='df'>dddd</a> 
                 </div> 
            
             </div>
            
          </div>

       
        </div>
```

Comment: Чудо какое то в панели "выполнить код" все корректно отображается, а у меня в коде нет. Весь дел провозился все проверял - не работает все во всех браузерах

Comment: @PNGH проверьте какое правило применяется для элемента в панели разработчика

Comment: Да все как и должно быть реальный код чуть сложнее но все же таже логика, никак не могу исправить проблему

Comment: @PNGH попробуйте продемонстрировать ссылкой, если нет хостинга - то есть бесплатные, а то тяжело что-то сказать не видя проблему

Comment: Я на локальном хосте - естественно не могу отправить в продакшн хост пока не решу проблему

Comment: @PNGH, _реальный код чуть сложнее но все же таже логика_ - отсюда следует вывод, что логика отличается. То есть разные либо структура разметки либо вложенность селекторов

Comment: Нет, совсем закодился , проблема такая - по моей логике  2, 3 элементы должный быть зелеными, но зеленый только 3 . Так что проблема не в разности кода

Comment: Я несколько подкорректировал вопрос

Comment: @PNGH текст второго элемента будет окрашен черным цветом, потому что селектор более точный, так что совсем непонятно, почему он должен быть зеленым - https://idg.net.ua/blog/uchebnik-css/azy-css/kaskadnost